# bash execute commands as different user with su

Tags: bash, dash-shell

I have the most simple issue and I am so not certain what I am doing wrong.

I have a simple shell script using /bin/sh

inside the script I have the following:

```
exec_as_wwwdata() {
 if [ $(whoami) = ${WWW_USER} ]]; then
    $@
  else
    su -s /bin/sh -c '$@' ${WWW_USER}
  fi
}
```

I am calling it with

```
exec_as_wwwdata composer config -g github-oauth.github.com $COMPOSER_GITHUB_TOKEN
```

it just does nothing, no error message nothing.
If I call the following directly inside the script

```
su -s /bin/sh -c 'composer config -g github-oauth.github.com $COMPOSER_GITHUB_TOKEN' ${WWW_USER}
```

it works.

What am I doing wrong here?

Based on feedback I have changed it to this

```
exec_as_wwwdata() {
 if [ $(whoami) = ${WWW_USER} ]]; then
    $@
  else
    su -s /bin/sh -c '"$@"' "$WWW_USER" _ "$@"
  fi
}
```

Although when I am calling it with the following arguments

```
exec_as_wwwdata /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/bin/composer create-project --repository-url=xxxx .
```

I receive the following error message

```
su: unrecognized option '--repository-url=
```

I think there is issue with -- in the string. How can I escape that ?

Comment: `'` `'` doesn't expand variables.

Comment: Replace `'` with `"`

Comment: Be aware that `"$@"` (yes, the quotes are important) will be treated *only* as a command name and its arguments; no pipes, no redirections, no `&&` or `||` operators.

Comment: Thanks for everyone for helping out. I have an additional issue now with double dashes. How do I escape that ?

Comment: Just a side note, you should generally use `"$VARNAME"` instead of `${VARNAME}`, because `${}` does not prevent word splitting, it just helps if you have adjacent characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two overlapping uses of `$@` here, and you've inadvertently stumbled on a partial correct solution. `-c` expects a single word, while `"$@"` would produce *multiple* distinct words. The correct solution would be

```
su -s /bin/sh -c '"$@"' "$WWW_USER" _ "$@"
```

The short version: you don't want to build a command string from the current parameters; you want to pass them as arguments to a hard-coded command string to let the new shell expand things appropriately.

A breakdown:

- `-s /bin/sh` - use `/bin/sh` instead of the appropriate users's login shell
- `-c '"$@"'` run the command `"$@"`, as desired. Note this is a hard-coded value; the new shell will expand its positional parameters correctly once it has started.
- `"$WWW_USER"` - specify the user to run the shell as
- `_` - specify the value of `$0` in the shell being run. You probably don't care what this value is; you just need some placeholder to prevent your first real argument from being treated as the value for `$0`.
- `"$@"` pass the *current* positional parameters as arguments to the new shell, which will expand *its* `"$@"` to these values.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed answer it is almost working. I did update the original to show the new error message now I am receiving. Thanks for any suggestion on this!!!

Comment: Look closely at my answer: I am use `-c '"$@'`, not `-c "$@"`.

Comment: Hi, you are absolutely right. I did modify the question. Although I am still getting the same error. it seems double dash is an issue somehow. It works well for other commands but if there is double dash like --repository it stops with the error message. Any idea why ?

Comment: Linux might be treating it as an argument to `su`, rather than an argument to the shell started by `su`. try `su -s /bin/sh -c '"$@"' "$WWW_USER" -- _ "$@"`